# Neither user 10232 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PROFILE

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-4.4-kitkat

When I launched the app on Samsung S3 neo  the app crashes with following Security Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10232 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PROFILE.
                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1472)
                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
                      at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:413)
                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:470)
                      at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65)
                      at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
                      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
                      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
                      at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ulguru.lms.myapplication">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`
        <activity android:name=".TabActivity1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ChooseLoginTypeActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".TabActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".UpCmngCourseListActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_video"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        -
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutUSActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about_us"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PurchaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_purchase"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".FeedBackActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_feed_back"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".OfflineVideoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_offline_video"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Login Activity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    static final int DIALOG_ERROR_CONNECTION = 1;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    String email;
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        sessionManager = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        if (hasConnection(LoginActivity.this)){
            //call methods
            //getJsonData();
        }
        else{
            showNetDisabledAlertToUser(LoginActivity.this);
        }

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

              /*check the interet connection*/


                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);


    }


    public boolean hasConnection(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        wifiNetwork=cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()){
            return true;
        }
        NetworkInfo mobileNetwork=cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()){
            return true;
        }
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void showNetDisabledAlertToUser(final Context context){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Would you like to enable it?")
                .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
                .setPositiveButton(" Enable Internet ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(dialogIntent);
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(" Cancel ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }


    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        /*if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }*/
        if(!myRequestLocation()){
            return;
        }
        if(!myRequestStorage()){
            return;
        }
        if(!mayRequestContacts()){
            return;
        }


        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

   private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean myRequestLocation(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                        }
                    });
        }else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }


        return false;
    }
    private boolean myRequestStorage(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }


        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {


            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {

            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

        mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }
    public boolean isOnline(Context c) {
        connectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (ni != null && ni.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {

        private final String mEmail ;
        private final String mPassword ;


        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }
       // String serverURL = "http://http://111.93.107.10/8080/AndroidRest/login/dologin?username='"+mEmail+"'&password='"+mPassword+"'";
        @Override

        protected  JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
            email = mEmail;


            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://111.93.107.10:6080/AndroidRest/login/dologin?email='"+mEmail+"'&password='"+mPassword+"'");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

                conn.connect();
                int status = conn.getResponseCode();
                switch (status) {
                    case 200:
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line+"\n");


                        }
                        br.close();
                        jsonArray  = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
                        System.out.println("upcoming responce message getting values="+sb);
                        return jsonArray;

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
            return jsonArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final JSONArray success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
            String msg = null;
            String username = null;
            if(jsonArray!= null) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("upcoming responce message after Regisration =" + jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("msg"));
                    msg = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("msg");
                    username= jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("username");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(msg.indexOf("invaid_email") != -1){
                    mEmailView.setError("Invalid Email");


                }
                if(msg.indexOf("invalid_password") != -1){
                    mPasswordView.setError("Invalid Password");


                }
                if(msg.equals("OK")){
                    System.out.println("no error go a head");
                    sessionManager.createLoginSession(username,email);
                    Intent intent  = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TabActivity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }



    }
}
```

What is the correct way to avoid this crash.Same code working on android 6.0 .

Comment: Did you try adding permission in the manifest file?

Comment: am already using  uses-permission on androidmanifestfile

Comment: Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />`.